# Freeswitch: Limit call duration

Tags: call, duration, freeswitch

Good day,

I write because I have a problem with my FreeSWITCH. The platform works well and out calls normally configured by the telephone provider, but lately I've had a problem with some long calls.

The problem is that sometimes the answering machine answers the called, and the other phones that also answers the answering calls by default. This makes call durations have up to 2 hours 30 minutes, where the answering speaking, and as no call this cut is kept active, which increases the costs unnecessarily.

I wonder if there is way to configure FreeSWITCH for all calls have a predetermined maximum duration. I've seen a module in FreeSWITCH (http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_sched_hangup), allegedly used to this but do not understand how it is used.

I would appreciate if anyone knows how to use this module, or I can give solution to this problem to avoid such long duration, or identify when an answering machine message sends tone after the call to cut

Answer (score 2):

Look at the sched_hangup application.

http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_sched_hangup